# Change ComboBox selection based on Bookmark in the Document

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-word, bookmarks

I'm new to vba and I've been working on a user form for a Word doc of mine. I'm trying to make a certain combobox select one of its items based on the text of a bookmark that's in  the document itself. I'm using an if statement to check the bookmark's text, and if it matches, it should change the combobox's selected item to one that I choose. I have very little knowledge of vba and I'm having trouble getting it to work. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Here is my code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.cbxShipFrom.AddItem ("My Company")
    Me.cbxShipFrom.AddItem ("Warehouse")
    Me.cbxShipFrom.AddItem ("Warehouse 2")
    Me.cbxShipFrom.AddItem ("Other...")

    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("shipfrom").Range.Text = "MY COMPANY" & vbCrLf & "123 BEETLE ST" & vbCrLf & "MYCITY, ST xZIPx" Then
        Me.cbxShipFrom.Value = Me.cbxShipFrom.ListIndex(0)
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use `CHR(13)` instead of `vbCrLf`

furthermore:

```
Me.cbxShipFrom.ListIndex(0)
```

isn't a valid expression since [ListIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845909.aspx) property returns an integer and not an array

you most probably want to use:

```
Me.cbxShipFrom.List(0)
```

and return the first element of the combobox list

finally you may want to use the following little refactoring of your code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.cbxShipFrom
        .AddItem ("My Company")
        .AddItem ("Warehouse")
        .AddItem ("Warehouse 2")
        .AddItem ("Other...")
        If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("shipfrom").Range.Text = "MY COMPANY" & Chr(13) & "123 BEETLE ST" & Chr(13) & "MYCITY, ST xZIPx" Then
            .Value = .List(0)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great! I didn't know about the with statement either, I can see it's potential for condensing down repetitive code. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. You're right about With statement, which also increases code performance since it avoids multiple memory accesses to the referenced object